# Is it possible to use custom elements with .Net Web Forms controls?

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element

When creating a custom element with a '-' in the tag name and using the attribute runat="server", the server tag is not well formed error appears when loading the page.

This is using Asp.Net 4.7. When you remove the hyphen in the tag, you have no issues or if you remove the runat="server" you have no issues.

```
<depth-chart runat="server" ></depth-chart>
```

I would expect this to run as is but .NET is not having that hyphen, a requirement for a custom element to be recognized by the browser. I'd like to be able to keep the dash and the runat attribute so that this custom element can be fiddled with on the .ascx and the .ascx.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by working around the parser on the .ascx file.

In the .ascx.cs file you can create a generic element with you own custom tag and the parser will not complain.

```
HtmlGenericControl depthChart = new HtmlGenericControl("depth-chart")
```

I added this control to the front with a `<asp:Placeholder>` as the parent.